# Can't write to new file in "w" or "w+" mode in C

Tags: c, file, pointers

I am new to the C and writing a code which I'll be taking flight data and simply write it to a text file. 
I debugged my code,and saw the values are saved to Flight array and when I open the file at `r+` mode, it writes the data and moves the pointer perfectly. But in a weird way, my `fseek()` functions doesn't work in my code, especially in the "w" or "w+" mode. I looked at the position of my pointer both in debugging window and with `ftell()` function, the position doesn't change. It is the same way with my other writing functions as well.

In the while block where I print my values with `printf()`, I used `ftell` to use in `fseek()`. Before that, I tried to use `*fseek(wfile,0,SEEK_END)*`. But my pointer still stands at the beginning and doesn't move, also `printf` doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#define MAX_CAPACITY 20
#define NEW_FLIGHT { "", "","","","","",MAX_CAPACITY,{'0'}}

typedef struct Flight 
{
    char airlineCompany[31];
    char flightNo[11]; //10 digit flight code
    char departureAirport[51];
    char arrivalAirport[51];
    char departureTime[6];
    char arrivalTime[6];
    int passengerCapacity;
    int passengers[MAX_CAPACITY]; //this array holds the value of 1/0:if seat is taken 1,else 0 .
} Flight;

void addFlight()
{
    system("cls");
    char another='y'; //variable to add another record
    int recordnumber=0;
    Flight flightarr[20]; //assuming 20 new record is written at a time,this is the flight array
    struct Flight flight=NEW_FLIGHT; //flight record

    FILE* wfile;//Writing a .txt database for flights

    wfile = fopen("flights.txt","r+"); //if cannot open the file...
    if(wfile == NULL)
    {
        wfile = fopen("flights.txt","w+"); //create one
        if(wfile= NULL)
        {
            printf("File not found !\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    int pos=ftell(wfile);
    printf("First pos:%d",&pos);
    while(another == 'y')
    {

        printf("Enter 10 Digit Flight Number:");
        scanf("%s",flight.flightNo);
        //printf("%s",flight.flightNo);
        printf("Airline Company:");
       // getchar();
       // fgets(flight.flightNo,30,stdin);
        scanf("%s",flight.airlineCompany);
        //printf("%s",flight.airlineCompany);
        printf("Departure Airport:");
        scanf("%s",flight.departureAirport);
        //printf("%s",flight.departureAirport);
        printf("Arrival Airport:");
        scanf("%s",flight.arrivalAirport);
        //printf("%s",flight.arrivalAirport);
        printf("Departure Time:");
        scanf("%s",flight.departureTime);
        //printf("%s",flight.departureTime);
        printf("Arrival Time:");
        scanf("%s",flight.arrivalTime);
        //printf("%s",flight.arrivalTime);
        printf("Passenger Capacity:");
        scanf("%d",&flight.passengerCapacity);
        //printf("%d",&flight.passengerCapacity);

        //assign the values to the flight array----------------

        strcpy(flightarr[recordnumber].flightNo,flight.flightNo);
        strcpy(flightarr[recordnumber].airlineCompany,flight.airlineCompany);
        strcpy(flightarr[recordnumber].departureAirport,flight.departureAirport);
        strcpy(flightarr[recordnumber].arrivalAirport,flight.arrivalAirport);
        strcpy(flightarr[recordnumber].departureTime,flight.departureTime);
        strcpy( flightarr[recordnumber].arrivalTime,flight.arrivalTime);
        flightarr[recordnumber].passengerCapacity=flight.passengerCapacity;
        recordnumber++;
        //------------------------------------------------------
        printf("\n Add another record? (Y/N)");
        fflush(stdin);
        another=getchar();

    }

    int i=0;

    while(i<recordnumber) //print to the file from array
    {
        fprintf(wfile, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %d \n", flightarr[i].flightNo,flightarr[i].airlineCompany,flightarr[i].departureAirport,flightarr[i].arrivalAirport,flightarr[i].departureTime,flightarr[i].arrivalTime,flightarr[i].passengerCapacity);
         int t = ftell(wfile);
        printf("Last pos:%d",&t);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(wfile); //close the file
}
```

Comment: The lines [`fflush(stdin);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) and `printf("Last pos:%d",&t);` will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `if (wfile = NULL)` ==> `if (wfile == NULL)`

Comment: @MikeCAT `printf(“Last pod: %d”, &t);` isn’t necessarily undefined but it is almost certainly not what you want. The `&` should just be removed to print the value itself.

Comment: @MikeCAT okay, i deleted the  'fflush(stdin);' but now it is not scanning value 'another'

Comment: @B.Morris `printf("Last pos:%d",&t);` is undefined because data having wrong type is passed. (`int*` is passed where `int` is expected) `printf(“Last pod: %d”, &t);` has only little chance to cause undefined behavior because it will lead to compilation error due to non-standard quotation marks.

Comment: @MikeCAT when I delete fflush() , it still doesn't write.When I delete fflush() and don't delete the printf("Last pos:%d",&t); it writes but this time,it owerwrites the file when I add new records.So, I deleted both of them and used fseek(),it worked this time but it kept adding the and of file without new line.Now I am back at where I started...I don't understand why